# How to get changes done by me one commit back?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert, unstage

I had lots of changes in my local git fork, I do:

1. `git add -A`
2. `git commit -m "commit message"`
3. pull changes from upstream master
4. rebase
5. `git push` to my origin

Now It happens that there are several other commits (from others) between my previous commit and my new commit.

I want to see all the changes done by me in my new commit and work on it.
So, I do

```
git reset --soft <my previous commit>
```

It shows files modified by me and also by others.

Question:

1. What would be the way to see files modified only by me?
2. And then the files are shown as modified, is it possible to unstage them? I want to see the changes when I do `git diff`.

Comment: Look into the docs of `git diff`. It's incredibly powerful!

Answer (score 5):

You are making things so complex. Instead of soft reset, simply use `git diff` and pass your commit and the one before to see what has been changed:

```
git diff xxxxxx yyyyyy
```

Where xxxxxx is the first and yyyyyy is the second commit hash values. To get the commit hash value use `git reflog`.

More info [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

UPDATE:

As suggested in comments, you can also use `git difftool xxxxxx yyyyyy` for a visual diff.

Comment: ... or `git difftool xxxxx yyyyy` for a visual diff. Maybe you could include that in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can filter only your commits then compare with HEAD.

```
$ git log --author=<user>           # see your  commits and copy commit-sha
$ git diff <commit-sha>..HEAD       # shows what is in HEAD that is not in <commit>
```